# css: smooth change of the text block height when changing the text length (change the number of letters in the text)

Tags: html, css, css-animations, height, css-transitions

there is a block of text

```css
.text-block {
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'header'></div>
<div class = 'text-block'>xxx</div>
<div class = 'footer'></div>
```

Can I use css (transition, etc.) to make it so that if text appears in a block that takes up more/less lines than it did, then the height of the block changes smoothly, i.e. the elements under the block (in the example - `<div class = 'footer'></div>`) will be smoothly lowered/raised on the page.

Comment: like when you you rezise page smoothly change layout?

Comment: @Neptotech -vishnu, For example, I dynamically insert larger text into a block and now instead of 5 lines the text takes up 10 lines, and the height of the block increases smoothly, not instantly

Answer (score 0):

### Use `transitions` (not *keyframe animation*)

- the transition works as a *AI* of `animation`
- it automatically detects `size`,`scale`,`margin`,`padding`,`left`,`right`,`up`,`down`.. changes
  and does animation/transformation

```css
.text-block {
    width: 100px;
}
.header, .text-block, .footer {
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'header'>header</div>
<div class = 'text-block'>xxx</div>
<div class = 'footer'>footer</div>
```

- Here i am using `ease-in-out` & `left` & `width`,you can use any other even

Comment: It is necessary to move up/down, change the height, while the height of the block is unknown. I.e., for example, the text takes 5 lines, as soon as it changes to a text of 10 lines, the block POSSIBLY increases its height. And the given code doesn't provide it :(